# How to make clicking the sidebar icon to show a quickview of all of the opened instances of the similar app?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gsettings

In Ubuntu 20.04,is it possible to make clicking the sidebar icon to show a glance of all of the opened instances of the similar app?

Is there any plugin or other OTC  GNOMEish desktop manager with such features?

And more info, please help me to get convinced to don't expect this capability by advising me on alternative practices...

(I forgot to mention that I've issued

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

to have click to minimize feature)

Comment: That is what it normally does by default ... does yours not do that?  What happens when you click an icon with open instances?  What happens when you right click?

Comment: Right-click on an icon in the dock and it'll show all open windows for that app.

Comment: @Bovine, I have changed it so that to minimizes single apps by one click. But when clicking multiple apps, it shows all of the apps instead of the ones of the same kind.

Comment: @heynnema, Thanks, It's acceptable.